# Can't get hot reload to work behind nginx in docker

Tags: docker, nginx, vue.js

I'm trying to setup a basic Vue app that lives in a docker container using docker compose and Nginx. My problem is that I can't get hot reloading to work. My current setup is as follows: 
- Using docker compose I create 2 containers. One for nginx and one for my vue app.
- I initialized my Vue app with the Vue CLI so it's a brand new project.
The Vue app container isn't exposed to the outside as it's all routed through nginx.

Hot reloading works fine outside of docker/nginx and while I can access the app while it's in a container hot reloading doesn't work. I've looked around and tried a ton of different nginx configurations but to no avail. I'm not super familiar with nginx and especially Vue (this is my first time experimenting with it). I'm not sure if it's a config issue on the side of Vue or Nginx.

Here is my current Nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  listen [::]:8080;

  location /app-api/ {
    proxy_pass http://app-api:8080;
  }

  location /app-ui/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_pass http://app-ui:8080;
  }

  location /sockjs-node/ {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_pass http://app-ui:8080;
  }
}
```

Here is my Vue config:

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/app-ui',
    devServer: {
        disableHostCheck: true,
        //https: true,
        overlay: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true
          }
    }
}
```

I have another app I was using as an example that has identical config (it's what I based this off of) and that app works with hot-reloading just fine so I know it's possible. However that project uses an older version of Vue and uses webpack directly instead of through the vue cli.

**Edit:** So it appears mabye it's not nginx that is the problem. I removed nginx and am just using the the app through docker-compose and i'm still getting the same issue. Here are the errors that i'm getting:
[image: Errors 1]
[image: Errors 2]

Comment: Typically you only use nginx after packaging the final app and the hot reloading only when doing local development. In other words, there's no real need for nginx during local dev

Comment: True I guess the main reason for using this method was to avoid having to have a separate port for each application and having to manage them all. With docker they can all have the same port and then nginx splits up the requests. I've seen it done before but for some reason it's giving me issues. I may just cut out nginx though if it gives me too much more trouble.

Comment: So I pulled out nginx to test that and i'm now encountering the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after realizing that my issue was not related to nginx I found [this](https://daten-und-bass.io/blog/enabling-hot-reloading-with-vuejs-and-vue-cli-in-docker/) blog post which game me an answer. It turns out that I needed to add an environment variable to my app's container like this:

```
environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Now my console is still getting spammed with errors but that seems to be a different issue entirely as hot reloading now works.